# Android Studio: RSS reader with xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, rss

I am trying to create an RSS reader from an xml file.

Most of my code is built off of this template: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm

I modified the code for my overall goal. The goal is to create a RSS feed with in a web based mobile application.

The problem is the app can not pull the rss feed properly. I get a statement saying your url can not be found.

Any help is much appreciated.

Activity Main

```
<TextView android:text="RSS example" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
    android:hint="Link"
    android:textColorHint="#ff69ff0e"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Result"
    android:id="@+id/button2"

    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />
```

Second Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Second

```
public class second extends Activity {
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    WebView w1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    w1.loadUrl("http://www.franklinpierce.edu/news.xml");
}
```

Main Activity Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText title,link,description;
Button b1,b2;
private String finalUrl="rss feed url";
private HandleXML obj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    link = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

RSSReader

```
public class RSSReader {
private String link = "link";
private String urlString = null;
private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

public HandleXML(String url){
    this.urlString = url;
}


public String getLink(){
    return link;
}


public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text=null;

    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();

        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name=myParser.getName();

            switch (event){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                    if(name.equals("link")){
                        link = text;
                    }


                    else{
                    }

                    break;
            }

            event = myParser.next();
        }

        parsingComplete = false;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void fetchXML(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                myparser.setInput(stream, null);

                parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                stream.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can not get the rss feed to work properly, so an error keeps coming up.

Comment: Your code seems to just load the xml into a webview? Where do you use the RSSReader class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you should be doing all the connections to a server with an AsyncTask. Here you go: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the url in an RSSReader class by passing it to the HandleXML and then you have to fetch it.

You will then have to figure out how you want to display the information.

loading the url into a webview is not even remotely close to what you want to do.